# Count repeat cells and where they appear

Tags: excel

I'm trying to set up a system to find only the unique values in one column, and if there are ones that aren't, list how many/which rows they appear in.

How it works is:
There are bags with hats in them. Bags have multiple hats, and the same hats can be spread out between different bags. I'm trying to eventually get to the point where I can look up a hat and it can tell me which bag(s) it's in.

I've looked up tutorials on Excel, but most of them seem to work on numbers, whereas my stuff has a 'serial' made up of letters that describes each item.

Consider the following:

```
╔════════╦═════╦═══════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ Serial ║ Bag ║   Style   ║ Colour ║  Size  ║
╠════════╬═════╬═══════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ SREDCP ║   1 ║ Cap       ║ Red    ║ Small  ║
║ SGRNST ║   2 ║ Straw hat ║ Green  ║ Small  ║
║ MGRYBN ║   3 ║ Beanie    ║ Grey   ║ Medium ║
║ SREDCP ║   4 ║ Cap       ║ Red    ║ Small  ║
╚════════╩═════╩═══════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

The item `SREDCP` appears in bags `1` and `4`. What I'd like is something like this:

```
╔════════╦════════╗
║ Serial ║ Bag(s) ║
╠════════╬════════╣
║ SREDCP ║    1,4 ║
║ SGRNST ║      2 ║
║ MGRYBN ║      3 ║
╚════════╩════════╝
```

I have almost zero experience in excel formulas, and I guess sql might be easier, but I have no idea how to set up a server or whatever the requirements are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array formula will do what you want:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$5, G2, 0)), MATCH(ROW($B$2:$B$5), ROW($B$2:$B$5)), ""))
```

Press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER after entering it instead of just enter as it is an array formula.

You can find details on how it works here:

https://www.get-digital-help.com/2017/12/05/index-match-multiple-results/

in particular step 3 on that page.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to create a column of the values you want to see for each Serial and then use TEXTJOIN on the column to get the list. So to the right of your data add a column headed SREDCP. Let's say F1 has 'SREDCP' in it. The in F2 add the formula `=IF($A2 = F$1, $B2, "")` and copy the formula down.

You hope to see a 1 and a 4 on those rows and blanks in between.

Then somewhere below add the formula `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,F2:F5)` and you'll see how this solution works.

The first parameter of TEXTJOIN adds the comma between terms, and the second one set to true tells Excel not to worry about blank cells.

Now to add the other Serials you can copy column F into column G and it is already set up, just change the Serial value in row 1.

But assuming your solution has more data than you showed, you might want to set up a working sheet with all of your Serials on it, and then to view the results reference that sheet. So move the columns F,G, etc to a new sheet. If you want.